# html email on iOS devices

Tags: html, ios, image, email

I am making a HTML email that will need to work on a variety of devices, there are two problems that are getting the better of me:

1)when viewing on an iOs device some of the images seem to be shifting by 1px when the email is first opened but when zoomed into the email the image seems to move back into place depending on the amount you are zoomed in(for example when the email is first opened there is a 1px line above some image and below others, then I zoom in a bit and the 1px line disappears, then I zoom in a bit more and the line reappeares). Is this a rendering problem with the iOS device or more likely a problem with the code?(The same problem occurs viewing hotmail, gmail and an outlook web access account via the iOS built-in mail function and while viewing in outlook web access via mobile safari)

2) I have asked this question from numerous people before and have been unable to come up with an answer(but I'll try my luck again). If I am sending an email from outlook 2007 to a web based email account is there any way to lock the formatting of the HTML email?(for example when  I send a HTML email from outlook 2007 to hotmail or gmail it loses its background color, spaces of about 7/8px appear below the images, the email losses its centring and appears floating to the left)

Any help would be greatly appreciated guys, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. I definitely think there is a problem with your code. The best way to send emails to iOS devices is to keep the emails as simple as possible, using as little HTML and CSS as possible and making sure that the code that you *do* use is supported in email clients.
2. Different browsers and mail clients will render your code differently. As with my above suggestion, keep the code to a minimum and design with flexibility in mind. Give images their own line, or use as few as possible to skip these sorts of issues.